# Preventing 'Add Field' in Multivalue Parameter for tool used in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, parameters, multi-values

I made a Field Picker script to allow the user to select field names which are then used in another script for more processing with update and insert cursors.

[image]

Is it possible to prevent them from adding their own field with the `Add Field` button?

[image]

If this button cannot be removed, is there a better way to get user input where they can select Field names and I can pass those as strings to another script?

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367411/model-builder-prevent-add-field-in-multivalue-parameter#comment601608_367411):

> You cannot remove that button. Just accept it is there and provide
> decent parameter help through it's item description to guide the user.